# Managing several vcenter hosts from one vsphere window

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have a couple of VMware hosts, 4.x and 5.x, on different networks etc. Is it possible to manage them from one instance of vCenter (virtual appliance) 5.5.0?

If so, where is the option to add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to depend a bit on your license and networking setup... But provided that you have a vCenter that's licensed to managed 3 or more hosts and can see each of the hosts over the requisite TCP ports (443, 902, etc.), this is possible.

Ideally, you want to create a separate vSphere "Datacenter" element for each location...

[image]

Then, within the "Actions" menu of each data center, you can simply choose the "Add Host..." option.

[image]

Comment: Hi I did try to add as above but got a bang about single server instances not being supported with the current licence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You add then the same way you add any host that you have a license for.